# Android multitouch - ignore one finger

Tags: android, multi-touch

[GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) has methods for a single finger, as well as for multiple fingers. How can I ignore one finger when there are few fingers on the screen and pass to it only a single finger?

Comment: i don't really know what you're trying to do, but "ignoring a finger" doesn't sound like a good idea.

still, `GestureDetector` seems to be aimed at detecting gestures for a single "finger".

Comment: I'd like to reuse the code I have in my class that implements GestureDetector. Even though it's not a good idea, I really need it :)

Comment: i still don't understand your need to "ignore a finger". anyway, you should be able to get data relative to different pointers out of a single `MotionEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do this...
Gesture detectors are supposed to listen to a pre-defined touch/motion event. If there are too many fingers on the screen, the pre-defined gesture won't happen...

You can, however, track regular multi-touch events and follow only, say, the first finger that touched the screen.
You can see a detailed explanation in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html).

Once a few fingers touch the screen, the generated `MotionEvent` will contain individual pointers to each one:

```
private int mActivePointerId;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ....
    // Get the pointer ID
    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

    // ... Many touch events later...

    // Use the pointer ID to find the index of the active pointer 
    // and fetch its position
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
}
```